# Do STL algorithms use multiple cores?

Tags: c++, multithreading, stl

Do the C++ STL algorithms use multiple-cores of the CPU **under the hood** for faster performance? If not, 
are there any recommended libraries to do what does STL does but with multiple cores, say using OpenMP? Or are there any switches one can specify during compilation with gcc  instructing STL to use multiple cores

EDIT: I am using Intel Core i7 960 processors, on Ubuntu 10.10 with gcc 4.4

Comment: According to which implementation? On which platform? And are you aware that the best that code can do is to multi-thread? It's up to the OS to dispatch to cores.

Comment: There's nothing to prevent them from using multiple cores, but it would depend on the library provider. As it would greatly complicate the code without benefiting the most common use cases, I'd guess nobody attempts it.

Comment: c tag removed. I think STL is C++ specific ...

Comment: Indeed.. perhaps the OP should specify a case where he feels that multiple cores would magically make Standard or STL algorithms "faster".

Comment: In general, no, because most of the STL algorithms end up calling user code for most types and there is no requirement that the user code is callable from multiple threads or concurrently.

Comment: Not all systems can use multi-threading so I don't think that STL algorithims would use such implementation.

Comment: @Lightness I don;t have any specific application in mind. Usually Data parallel Algorithms can take advantage of multiple-cores or even CUDA to get faster performance. I am using the gcc implementation of the STL.

Comment: @k3oy This is probably a dumb question, but by "systems" do you mean CPU's?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: it would certainly be peculiar to claim that no standard algorithm could ever be made faster by parallelization. I realise nobody has quite made that claim, but I'm slightly surprised by Lightness's degree of astonishment at the idea. I think James has the key point here - you can't safely replace a loop with OpenMP "parallel for" unless you have the "permission" of the loop body. I'd guess there are common cases though where the optimizer could do enough inlining to prove that the algorithm is parallelizable. `copy`, `transform` or `sort` with simple enough parameters.

Comment: @smilingbuddha CPU's and OS's as well, as far as I know some old OS's can't use multi-threading functions.

Comment: @k3oy: I think STL is probably used here in the inaccurate sense of, "the standard algorithms". The "real" STL is a bunch of header files published by SGI back in the day, simple inspection of them shows that they did not parallelize. But C++ implementations don't have to use that exact code, don't have to target the systems you're talking about if they don't want to, and even if they do can have conditionally-compiled code to use or not use particular features like threading.

Comment: The GCC implementation of the STL is in fact the GCC implementation of the C++ Standard Library, i.e. libstdc++. There is no "GCC implementation of the STL"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

GNU libstdc++ seems to have a parallel mode that supports several parallelization features for STL:

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/parallel_mode.html

Answer (score 4):

I know of no STL implementation that leverages multiple cores.  Even if one does exist, you need to ensure that the added complexity ends up as a net benefit.  The types of algorithms STL provides (sort, accumulate, etc.) benefit from parallelism only in fairly extreme circumstances (e.g. > 10 million elements).  If you only leverage parallelism at the STL level, you are probably going to be disappointed in the results.

I would look at Intel's TBB (http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/) which provides a task-based parallelism framework.  It encourages algorithm design that is amenable to task-based scheduling and not just a bunch of leaf functions (e.g. parallel_sort() although TBB does provide one).

Answer (score 1):

The C++ standard neither requires nor prohibits parallel execution of standard algorithms.

There have been a number of parallel implementations. In addition to libstdc++ parallel mode (which was mostly based on [MCSTL](http://algo2.iti.kit.edu/singler/mcstl/)) there are [STAPL](https://parasol.tamu.edu/stapl/), and [OMPTL](http://tech.unige.ch/omptl/) (which is also included in [CVMLCPP](http://tech.unige.ch/cvmlcpp/index.html)). There has been a fair amount of other work, but development of libstdc++ parallel mode seems to have killed quite a few other projects.